# Installing FTP on CentOS 7

Tags: ftp

I tried to install both proftpd(manually) and vsftpd(via yum) and I still can't get what I want. I want to allow users to get access to their home folders. It's a typical aim.
Both servers was installed without errors, I configured it, but I can't restart anyone normally like this:

```
service vsftpd restart
```

It fails. 
If go to `ftp://localhost` via browser, I can see the only one folder named "pub" and it is empty. I don't even now which server is running now (vsftpd or proftpd). I am absolutely new to Linux and CentOS and don't know how to find it out.
How to correct the startup of one of these servers?

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7 uses systemd by default. Maybe what your are looking for is:

```
systemctl start vsftpd.service
```

Also take a look at logs and journalctl.

Comment: Well, that helped to start service. Thank you! But now, when I go to `ftp://localhost` and enter username/password I get alert "500 OOPS: chroot".

Comment: Fixed by commenting the line `chroot_local_user=YES`. But there is another problem. I can't to connect to ftp from local network using `ftp://192.168.0.103`. My CentOS7 launched inside Hyper-V machine. I try to get access to it from parent PC. Important to say that this method worked fine with Ubuntu VM and proftpd, but now it doesn't work with CentOS7 and vsftpd. Where the problem might be?

Comment: Take a look at your firewall settings. Maybe FTP isn't allowed by default. 
As I understand you are able to ping VM as well as connect using ssh.
To debug this you can also try to connect to ftp localy inside VM and see if it works.

Comment: It works if go to `ftp://localhost` inside VM. I can ping VM from ouside, but I can't connect to FTP from outside, It doesn't respond.